# Using bibliometrix, how do I extract the exact author in the Hindex function?

Tags: r, bibliography

In the below code, the estimated `h-index` of authors is calculated.

```
library(bibliometrix)
results <- biblioAnalysis(df, sep = ";")
indices$CitationList
authors=gsub(","," ",names(results$Authors)[1:10])
indices <- Hindex(M16, field = "author", elements=authors, sep = ";", years = 50)
```

Then outputted onto a table, like the one below using `indices$H`

```
      Author h_index g_index m_index TC NP PY_start
1     TSAI CC       6       8     1.2 69 11     2016
2  ZEMBYLAS M       5       7     1.0 60 11     2016
3   BOGNER FX       4       6     0.8 43 10     2016
4       KIM H       3       4     0.6 22 10     2016
5       KIM J       5       9     1.0 82 10     2016
6      WANG J       3       3     0.6 21 10     2016
7       LEE J       2       5     0.4 27  9     2016
8   MARTIN AJ       3       6     0.6 45  8     2016
9    TAYLER C       4       6     0.8 38  8     2016
10    COHEN A       2       4     0.4 24  7     2016
```

The issue I have is with common names like `LEE J` on row 7. How do I identify, from the `results` data, this specific `LEE J`? Thanks for help!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear - I didn't want to subset the data within `indIces$h`, I wanted to subbed LEE J's data from the `results` object, created in the previous lines.

Comment: Can you show a `dput` of few lines of `df`

Comment: Something like `indices$H[indices$H$Author == "LEE J", ]` might work. But as akrun said, `dput` of `df` would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The `results` would be a `list` object and `Authors` is a frequency table of counts with `names` as author name.  If that is case, we can use `grep` to identify names with substring matches for 'LEE J'

```
i1 <- grep("LEE J", names(results$Authors))
results$Authors[i1]
```

Or use `==` for exact matches

```
results$Authors[names(results$Authors) == "LEE J"]
```